# How can I get numeric value of Sunday to 1

Tags: php

I am trying to get numeric value of `Sunday` as `1`

```
$day_of_week = date('N', strtotime('Sunday'));
```

returns `7`.

Can I get `1` instead of `7`?

Comment: what about other days?

Comment: My question is why you want that? Any specific reason?

Comment: Please tag your questions appropriately; this has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: `date('w', …) + 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I get 1 instead of 7?

A short look into the manual for `date` should have enabled you to discover that there’s not only the format specifier `N`, which gives you

> 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

but also `w`, which gives you

> 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)

So if you want values from 1 for Sunday to 7 for Saturday, then all you need to do is use that, and add 1 to it afterwards:

```
$day_of_week = date('w', strtotime('Sunday')) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$day_of_week = date('w', strtotime('Sunday'));
echo $day_of_week + 1;
```

You can use this method because there are only two way for get week days one is 'N' which you are using which returns 1-7 But monday is first day

Second is 'w' is returns 0-6 And Sunday is first day so you just need addition for number 1